# Trouble Including GoogleTest in Visual Studio C++ Project

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code, cmake, header-files, googletest

I'm encountering an issue while trying to set up GoogleTest in my C++ project using Visual Studio and CMake. Here are the relevant details:

**Project Structure:**

- Root Directory:

  - CMakeLists.txt
  - tests

    - test_main.cpp
    - calc_test.cpp
  - src

    - calc.cpp

**CMakeLists.txt:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project("EX1") # Replace “MyCalc” with your repo name

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
googletest
URL
https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed
33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)

enable_testing()
set(SOURCE_FILES
    src/calc.cpp # this is where the code we want to test
)

set(TEST_FILES
    tests/test_main.cpp # this is the main for tests
    tests/calc_test.cpp # this file contain the tests
)

add_executable(CalcTests ${TEST_FILES})

# Link Google Test to the test executable
target_link_libraries(CalcTests PRIVATE gtest gtest_main)

# Include the source directory for tests
target_include_directories(CalcTests PRIVATE src)

include(GoogleTest)
add_test(NAME CalcTests COMMAND CalcTests)
```

Issue:
When running cmake --build build, I'm getting the following errors:

```
C:\Users\BLA\Desktop\Code\GitHub\Ex1\tests\test_main.cpp(1,10): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\BLA\Desktop\Code\GitHub\Ex1\build\CalcTests.vcxproj]
C:\Users\BLA\Desktop\Code\GitHub\Ex1\tests\calc_test.cpp(1,10): error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h': No such file or directory [C:\Users\BLA\Desktop\Code\GitHub\Ex1\build\CalcTests.vcxproj]
```

Question:

What could be causing the "Cannot open include file: 'gtest/gtest.h'" error during the build process?

How can I correctly configure my CMakeLists.txt and Visual Studio project to include GoogleTest for testing?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

(when I'm moving the files inside the directories src and test outside of there directory, i get no error. its like when they are in their directory they can't fine the header file of gtest... do u know the solution?)

Comment: `target_link_libraries(CalcTests PRIVATE gtest gtest_main)` should be `target_link_libraries(CalcTests PRIVATE GTest::gtest GTest::gtest_main)`

Comment: You forgot to use `FetchContent_MakeAvailable`

Answer (score 1):

Add `FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)`:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.14)
project("EX1") # Replace “MyCalc” with your repo name

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD_REQUIRED ON)

include(FetchContent)
FetchContent_Declare(
    googletest
    URL https://github.com/google/googletest/archive/03597a01ee50ed33e9dfd640b249b4be3799d395.zip
)

FetchContent_MakeAvailable(googletest)

enable_testing()
set(SOURCE_FILES
    src/calc.cpp # this is where the code we want to test
)

set(TEST_FILES
    tests/test_main.cpp # this is the main for tests
    tests/calc_test.cpp # this file contain the tests
)

add_executable(CalcTests ${TEST_FILES})

# Link Google Test to the test executable
target_link_libraries(CalcTests PRIVATE GTest::gtest GTest::gtest_main)

# Include the source directory for tests
target_include_directories(CalcTests PRIVATE src)

include(GoogleTest)
add_test(NAME CalcTests COMMAND CalcTests)
```

See the [manual](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/module/FetchContent.html)

Comment: I included this (which was present in the previous version but was accidentally deleted), but it still isn't functioning. In the link below there is information that could assist me in resolving the issue?

Comment: It should fix the include errors. If you get other errors, post a new question.

Comment: I get the same errors..

Comment: I've tested it locally - there're no include errors. You seem to use other files, not those in the question.

Comment: when I'm moving the files inside the directories src and test outside of there directory, i get no error. its like when they are in their directory they can't fine the header file of gtest... do u know the solution?

Comment: Again, as it shown in the question, it compiles well.